# Show that the minimum of $f$ does not occur at an endpoint.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

> Let $f$ be a differentiable function on $[a,b]$ but the derivative may be discontinuous. Suppose that $f'(a)<0<f'(b).$ Show that the minimum of $f$ does not occur at an endpoint. What can you conclude?

Here's my work so far

Since $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b],$ it is continuous on $[a,b].$ We want to show that neither $f(a)$ nor $f(b)$ is a minimum. Since $f$ is continuous and $f'(a)<0<f'(b),$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\exists x\in [a,a+\delta)$ such that $f(x)<f(a)$. By the definition of a derivative, since $f'(a)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}.$ We thus have that $\forall \epsilon >0,\exists \delta >0$ such that $0<h<\delta\Rightarrow \left|\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}-f'(a)\right|<\epsilon$ (I'm pretty sure this is correct). So we have that $f(a+h)<f(a)+h(f'(a)+\epsilon).$ In particular, this is true if $\epsilon +f'(a)<0\Rightarrow f(a+h)<f(a).$ Thus there exists an $x\in [a,a+\delta)$ such that $f(x)<f(a).$ Similarly, $f'(b)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(b+h)-f(b)}{h}$ and so by the $\epsilon-\delta$ limit definition, $\forall \epsilon >0,\exists \delta >0$ such that $-\delta < h <0\Rightarrow\left|\dfrac{f(b+h)-f(b)}{h}-f'(b)\right|<\epsilon\Rightarrow f(b+h)>f(b)+h(f'(b)-\epsilon).$

In particular, this holds for $\epsilon \leq f'(b)\Rightarrow b+h < b$ and $f(b+h)<f(b).$ Thus $f(x)$ cannot have a local minimum at $b.$

Thus, I can conclude by the Extreme Value Theorem that the minimum is attained in $(a,b).$

Comment: $f$ need not be decreasing near $a$; but you can show that there is an $x$ near $a$ with $f(a)>f(x)$.

Comment: An example of what I allude to above is $f(x)=x+2x^2\sin(1/x)$ for $x\ne0$, $f(0)=0$. $f'(0)=1$, here; but $f'$ takes both positive and negative values in any nhood of $0$.

Comment: @DavidMitra I've edited my answer. I may have to make some more minor adjustments, but I think it's much better than last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the comments by @ David Mitra, $f$ need not be monotonic in a nbhd of $a$ nor in a nbhd of $b.$

$f'(a)<0$ so there exists $x\in (a,b)$ with $\frac {f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<f'(a)+|\frac {f'(a)}{2}|=\frac {f'(a)}{2}<0,$ so $f(x)<f(a).$

$f'(b)>0$ so there exists $x'\in (a,b)$ with $\frac {f(b)-f(x')}{b-x'}>f'(b)-|\frac {f'(b)}{2}|=\frac {f'(b)}{2}>0,$ so $f(b)>f(x').$

Comment: Yes. I just re-wrote my A. I always have to edit my posts.  Read them before I edit at your own risk.

Comment: Not  because $f$ is continuous but because of the values of $f'$ at $a$ and $b$.

Comment: So you're saying it's *solely* because of the values of $f'$ at $a$ and $b,$ right? That gives me a better idea of how I'm going to prove this.

Comment: Daniel.Please elaborate:$\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<f'(a)+|f'(a)|/2$. Where does this come from?Thanks.

Comment: $f'(a)=\lim_{a<x\to a}V(x)$ where $V(x)=\frac {f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.$ So for any $r>0$ there exists $x_r\in (a,b)$ with $|V(x_r)-f'(a)|<r,$ which implies $V(x)<f'(a)+r.$ Now let $r\in (0,|f'(a)|),$ & conclude that $f(x_r)<f(a).$ I chose $r=|f'(a)|/2$ for convenience.... Also, from the basics, if  $f(x)\ge f(a)$ for all $x\in (a,b)$ then $V(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in (a,b)$ but then $V(x)$ could not converge to the negative value $f'(a)$ as $x\to a$ (which is simpler than my A).

Comment: @PeterSzilas. My most recent comment above was meant for you.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet.Thanks.

Comment: @DanielWeinfleet. Why not include your proof by contradiction in your answer?Nice.